# Regex - any one or more character followed by one new line and equal sign

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm making an open-source Markdown parser.

I have a bit of problem on my regex as I'm not very expert on regex.

```
r = r.replace(/(.*)(\n=$)/g, '<h1>$1</h1>');
```

What I want here is to get any one or more character follow by `\n` new line and the next line would be one or more of `=` only.

Input is:

`Hello World\n===`

Expected output:

## Hello World

The one I have worked but when I have two new lines it will strip off the equal signs too.

So if I have something like this

`Hello World\n\n===`

I should see this

```
Hello World

===
```

Comment: Sorry my title was wrong :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an end anchor (`$`) which means it will only match of there are no other characters following the first equals. Furthermore, it looks like you want to be able to match one or more equals signs.

I think this is what you want:

```
"Hello World\n===".replace(/(.+)\n=+/g, '<h1>$1</h1>'); // <h1>Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: Should I use \r\n? or just \n would be enough?

Comment: @Ali That depends on your particular use cases. If you *know* the input will only have `\n`, I'd use that for simplicity. If you want to support any line common ending, I'd use `(\r?\n|\r)`, which will work with `\n`, `\r`, or `\r\n`.

Comment: so it will be like `(/(.+)(\r?\n|\r)=+/g, '<h1>$1</h1>');` ??

Comment: @Ali Yes, that's right. If this is coming from a database or something like that, I'd recommend normalizing the line endings before you save them in the database, though. That way you won't have to clean them up via JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
(.+)\r\n=+

r = r.replace(/(.+)\r\n=+/g, '<h1>$1</h1>');
```

Answer (score 1):

To match headers properly, I would suggest to use a start-of-string anchor as well, i.e.:

```
s.replace(/^(.+)$\r?\n={3,}/gm, '<h1>$1</h1>')
```

I'm using `^` to match the start and `$` to match the line ending, in conjunction with the `/m` modifier they will operate on lines rather than the whole subject.

Then, `\r?\n` will munge exactly one line ending (CRLF or LF). Finally the `={3,}` will match three or more equal signs.

Comment: I like that :D really great for matching three or more equal signs :)

Comment: But actually one problem here. it is stripping off the equal signs if there was two extra lines :/